# How can I enable .xml syntax highlighting for .xaml files?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, filetype, vim9

I am trying to enable `.xml` syntax highlighting in Vim for `.xaml` files since `.xaml` files don't have syntax highlighting of its own. I came across a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584359/vim-for-xaml-editing) on Stack Overflow which recommended to use `au BufNewFile,BufRead *.xaml setf xml` but that did not provide syntax highlighting as soon as I open the `.xaml` file. I can see below on the console that the `.xaml` files are changed to `.xml` filetype.

I tried what this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/383211/turning-on-xml-syntax-highlighting-in-vim-for-a-non-xml-file) suggested: `autocmd BufEnter *.xaml :setlocal filetype=xml` but this does not provide syntax highlighting either.

I even tried modifying it to: `autocmd BufEnter *.xaml :setlocal filetype=xml | syntax on` but it causes several glitches and formats the syntax higlighting of all my other open tabs & windows as `.xml`. Any suggestions are deeply appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `syntax on` (if you must, use `syntax enable`). Does syntax highlighting work for `.xml` files? What filetype is reported in a `.xml` file? The best way to add simple filetype rules is to create a file `~/.vim/ftdetect/xaml.vim` with `autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.xaml setfiletype xml`, though sometimes you want `set filetype=xml` instead. Can you [edit] to answer these questions and clarify what "it does not behave…" or "syntax highlighting does not function" mean?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I apologize. I've made the edits to further clarify as you reqested!

Comment: Thanks, what about the first questions? Does syntax highlighting work for `.xml` files? What is their filetype?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes! `.xml` syntax highlighting does work but I have to enable it while in vim, I have to `:set filetype=xml` & then `:syntax on/enable`. This way, I do get proper syntax highlighting for '.xaml' files as well.

Comment: Have you tried [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604)? What does your minimal vimrc that reproduces the problem look like?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I will try this. If anything, I'll re-install or try to map the command to a key or something. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming all works as you wish it when you enter `:set filetype=xml` when your XAML file is open in a buffer, try this: create file `~/.vim/ftdetect/xaml.vim` containing the following:

```
" Detects XAML files as XML
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.xaml setlocal filetype=xml
```

This has worked for me for other "odd" file types.

Comment: @JoseMembreno Does this answer work for you? I ask because you've marked it as accepted, but your comment says it doesn't work. If it does work, please delete the comment so as not to confuse future readers. Thanks